# How do I reset the interface for Azure Language Service (Custom Question Answering) to its default

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I tried to modify some question and answer pairs and notice that the interface has changed considerable. Actually I don't have a clue what to do anymore.

Does anybody know how to change it back to how it was. I can't find an option to change the interface.

[image]

I tried to find ways to reset\change the interface or find documentaion why it has changed but did not fund anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the existing and upload the docx that you are referring.

Comment: thanks but I was referring to the interface of Lanugage Studio. It has changed considerably.